# Birt Exception -Processing Document File,Try again

Tags: birt

I am getting birt exception like 'Processing document file,Tyr Again' when i try to generate birt reports in pdf.
I doubt it is because of timeout since it is taking lot of time to generate report.
I searched in net but could not find desired solution for this.Plese help.

Comment: If you open the same report as a web page do you have the same problem?

Comment: yes I am getting this exception while i am trying to run as web page.It takes lot of time to load before getting this exception and I am getting data from Excel file and database for this report from a backend java code.

Comment: Do you have an earlier version of the report that runs without the problem?  Like an early draft durring report construction.

Comment: yes i have it and it works fine...only this report giving problem.